# limit date for 1 week in tapestry5

Tags: java, date, tapestry

I have a datefield in tapestry5. The datefield is a field in the entity. I want the datefield can clicked only for 7 last days. example rightnow is 1 Aug. The datefield only can be clicked on 26 july until 1 aug. Can it possible?

if it is too complicated, can i limit date for 1 week, if the user click on 25 july or 2 aug, sysout or log or message or anything can be show up to say. Please click only current date or 7 days before rightnow.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just convert to calender object and check with using cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7). And check the date the user chacked is above cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7).